Upgraded Ansible Lint and now it no longer recognises ansible.windows modules
I was using an old version of ansible-lint (v6 something) on my mac (m1+sonoma). I ran brew update ansible-lint and now I am on version 24.6.0 but now in VSCode I am getting the following lint messages:
couldn't resolve module/action 'ansible.windows.win_powershell'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.
This occurs for all the ansible.windows modules plus community.windows modules.
The playbooks run fine, its just ansible-lint is giving me the message but on the previous version I was using it was fine, no messages.
I ran ansible-lint --version and got the following which suggests the local setup is broken but I have no idea what to check or change to get it working. I ran brew uninstall ansible-lint to remove it then reinstalled it but I get the same issue.
WARNING: PATH altered to include /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible-lint/24.6.0_1/libexec/bin, /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible-lint/24.6.0_1/libexec/bin :: This is usually a sign of broken local setup, which can cause unexpected behaviors.
ansible-lint 24.6.0 using ansible-core:2.17.1 ansible-compat:24.6.1 ruamel-yaml:0.18.6 ruamel-yaml-clib:0.2.8

Recent versions of ansible-lint are having issues with modules with _ in their FQCN. I observe the same behavior for e.g. cisco.ios collection.

My guess is that you are running ansible-lint in a python environment where only ansible-core is available (i.e. without any pre-bundled collection) whereas your run your playbook in an other where a full blown ansible installation with all collections including ansible.windows are available. Make sure you install the linter in the same environment and for that I highly suggest you stop using any packaging tool besides the officially supported one => pip. Anyhow, I cannot reproduce your issue in a clean virtualenv
